# Cross correlation of a non-stationary process

Tags: random, correlation

I'm trying to get the cross correlation between two vector samples from [flicker noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_noise). The power spectral density is given by:
$$N_o\big(1+\frac{f_{corner}}{f}\big),$$ where $N_o$ is the noise floor assumed to $-100dB$, $f_{corner}$ is a parameter of the noise and $f$ is the frequency variable.

From a paper ([here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.322750?class=pdf)), it is already shown that the flicker noise process is non-stationary in the time domain. I have two time-domain vector samples of the process of length $n$ and I need to find the cross correlation matrix between them and observe if the off-diagonal entries are non-zero (check for non-zero correlation). Since the process is non-stationary, the sample values themselves depend on the time they're sampled.

Does this imply that for any two vector samples of the process at different times, the cross-correlation is non-zero?